# Blank page in Magento on XAMPP

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to set up a local copy of a Magento site on XAMPP (on OS X) and am getting a blank page, even though I've run through the list of usual offenders for this issue. I've increased the memory limit to 256M, set error reporting to E_ALL, checked that the magento index.php file is being hit, checked from the index.php file that errors are indeed switched on (using ini_get('display_errors')). I checked /var/cache but Magento hasn't created the cache directory in /var for my install.

Is there anything else that could be the issue? I tried the same install on a LAMP setup on Ubuntu and it worked fine. Unfortunately, nothing in the error logs in XAMPP to help.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There are 1,000,0001 things that could be the issue.  Let's knock one off: are you actually *outputting anything* in index.php?

Comment: try to add index.php at the end of the url, sometimes in local can be the problem

Comment: check file access (chmod).

Comment: @Madbreaks - yeah, sorry that's what i meant, I can echo out from index.php all the way to the Mage::run line at the end

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri tried that too, but it didn't change anything

Comment: You should definitely see some sort of error logging. Is it a fresh copy of Magento CE? Ie no modules/modifications?

Comment: I've cloned a git repo to work on locally. Cloning the repo works fine on LAMP in Ubuntu I've got on a VM. Must be an issue with the XAMPP environment, but I really don't get why the error isn't being logged

Comment: If it is already installed elsewhere, have you migrated the DB and setup MySQL and the user?

Comment: you need to first focus on these two things.1)echo something on index.php followed by exit and see something on screen. 2) Make sure that Mage::log can be used to log errors plus Reports can be viewed.

Comment: Hello, please attach: server error logs, php error logs, magento logs and Magento version.

Comment: Enable developer mode (`Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);`) and see if that helps with error output.

Comment: if you have local.xml in your app/etc/ folder, but the database credentials are incorrect, this is probably the issue. if you never played with magento before just remove the tables in your database and remove local.xml file. magento should point to to installer to start everything from scratch ;)